# Oracle Select invalid identifier error from a table created with create as select statement

Tags: oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g and I created a table B using a create as select statement.
The creation was succeeded :

`create table B as select * from A;`

HOWEVER when a run a Select on specific columns of B I got an error ORA-00904 : "Mycolumn_C": invalid identifier.

BUT when I run a select * from B , it works fine !

The point is that "MyColum_C" is an alias in the select statement on table A , as follows :

```
Create table B as select  code, name, useday as "Mycolum_C", validperiod as "Mycolum_D, enddate from A
```

For some reason,  select statement on newly created table B of those columns that had aliases on table A,  generates erro invalid identifier.

Examples of statements that fails :

```
Select Mycolum_C from B
Select Mycolum_D from B
```

What is going on here ?

Any help is very welcome !

Comment: `"Mycolum_C"` is a different column name than `Mycolum_C`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Comment: Well, by  enclosing column names in double quotation as worked !  But why should I do that for aliases column in source slect statement ?